# Returns errors when passing a phone number in authorization

Tags: python, authentication, pyrogram

Returns errors when passing a phone number in authorization in pyrogram,I don't know what the problem is, please help

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nikitamakarov/PycharmProjects/pythonProject12/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    sent_code_info = client.send_code(phone_number)
  File "/Users/nikitamakarov/PycharmProjects/pythonProject12/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/sync.py", line 66, in async_to_sync_wrap
    return loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/nikitamakarov/PycharmProjects/pythonProject12/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/auth/send_code.py", line 54, in send_code
    r = await self.invoke(
  File "/Users/nikitamakarov/PycharmProjects/pythonProject12/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/advanced/invoke.py", line 79, in invoke
    r = await self.session.invoke(
  File "/Users/nikitamakarov/PycharmProjects/pythonProject12/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/session/session.py", line 389, in invoke
    return await self.send(query, timeout=timeout)
  File "/Users/nikitamakarov/PycharmProjects/pythonProject12/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/session/session.py", line 357, in send
    RPCError.raise_it(result, type(data))
  File "/Users/nikitamakarov/PycharmProjects/pythonProject12/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/errors/rpc_error.py", line 91, in raise_it
    raise getattr(
pyrogram.errors.exceptions.flood_420.FloodWait: Telegram says: [420 FLOOD_WAIT_X] - A wait of 44927 seconds is required (caused by "auth.SendCode")
```

```
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram.errors import SessionPasswordNeeded, PhoneCodeInvalid, PasswordHashInvalid

api_id = YOUR_API_ID
api_hash = "YOUR_API_HASH"
phone_number = "YOUR_PHONE_NUMBER"
client = Client(":memory:", api_id, api_hash)
client.connect()
sent_code_info = client.send_code(phone_number)
phone_code = input("Please enter your phone code: ")  # Sent phone code using last function
while True:
    try:
        client.sign_in(phone_number, sent_code_info.phone_code_hash, phone_code)
        break
    except SessionPasswordNeeded:
        password = input("Please enter your pass: ")  # Sent phone code using last function
        try:
            client.check_password(password)
            break
        except PasswordHashInvalid:
            print("pass error try 1 more time")
    except PhoneCodeInvalid:
        print("code error try 1 more time")


client.send_message("me", "Thats work!") #Checking work
```

Comment: add time.sleep()??